# Is there a export to pdf plugin for ngtable?

Tags: pdf, ngtable

Getting my head around ngtable but what I cant find is a way to export the tabledata to a pdf format? Is there any plugin available that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

We implemented http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf with ng-table. Here's a fiddle to the sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/js64b/1181/

The relevant code is below. The one trick is to be sure to pass the option "namespaces" into the formatter to include (any) reference to the ng: namespace. In the example below, we just point it to "http://www.foo.net".

This is required as the content from the HTML DOM is scraped with these in place, turned to XML and transformed. This technique puts this (disregarded) namespace on the document so that it is not an error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" ng:autobind
src="http://code.angularjs.org/0.10.5/angular-0.10.5.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.cloudformatter.com/Resources/Pages/CSS2Pdf/Script/xeponline.jqplugin.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.cloudformatter.com/Resources/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="printme">
  <table ng:controller="SortableTableCtrl">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng:repeat="(i,th) in head" ng:class="selectedCls(i)" ng:click="changeSorting(i)">{{th}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng:repeat="row in body.$orderBy(sort.column, sort.descending)">
        <td>{{row.a}}</td>
        <td>{{row.b}}</td>
        <td>{{row.c}}</td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<button onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('printme',{render:'download',namespaces:['xmlns:ng=&quot;http://www.foo.net&quot;']});">PDF</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's not specifically built for ngtable, a plugin called jsPDF may work for you.

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

or the git

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF